# Slash at the end of the breadcrumbs

Tags: breadcrumbs

How can I remove the slash at the end of my breadcrumbs?

*Markup:*

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <a href="/">Главная</a>
    /
  <a href="/admin">Управление</a>
    /
  <a href="/admin/build">Конструкция сайта</a>
</div>
```

*Screenshot:*

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I guess the slash is not in the end. It is the way you styled your breadcrumb thats why you are seeing it in the end. You can aid it using CSS, just tweak it a bit so you can hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following into your template.php file:

```
function MYTHEMENAME_breadcrumb($breadcrumb) {
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    return '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode('  ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
  }
}
```